# Select the first record from a Select Values ​in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I would like to retrieve the first record of this list. It is generated by reading all the paths contained in a given folder.
[this is the pentaho flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFlci.png)
[this is the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDHcw.png)

Comment: can't you use a simple "sample rows" step? Or am i misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @Bert-JanStroop thanks for the answer, I didn't know the command, but i just try and it is perfect, thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the step "Sample row" can fetch for you the needed number of rows.